# Using ModelBuilder Query method with inherited classes (EF core 2.1)

Tags: inheritance, stored-procedures, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have some problem with using dbContext Query method on base class which provide some inheritance to one other class (just for inherit properties, not for model / db building)

In my repo services I call something like:

```
IEnumerable<CoasterExtended> coasters = await _db.Query<CoasterExtended>()
            .FromSql(GetCoastersProcedure, pageNumberParam, pageSizeParam, orderByParam, sortParam, breweryIdParam, searchParam, coasterTypeParam)
            .ToListAsync();
```

GetCoastersProcedure is a sql procedure which return all properties of CoasterExtended class. This class is not used to model / db build. It is just mirror of sql procedure result.

In my OnModelCreating method i just have:

```
builder.Query<CoasterExtended>();
```

Querying the result of sql procedure worked fine until I decided to use this class for inheritance:

```
public class CollectionItemExtended : CoasterExtended {
    // some additional properties
}
```

And the OnModelCreating method:

```
builder.Query<CollectionItemExtended>();
```

The query (of CoasterExtended type) now return error "The required column 'Discriminator' was not present in the results of a 'FromSql' operation". I know that discriminator is used for inherited types, but I use both classes to mirror the result of separate sql procedures (these results I simply map to desired app model classes)

So I dont want to select (and fake) discriminator ... I just want to map results of sql procedures to independent classes (which I have inherited just because I dont want to duplicate properties and mappers which are following). How can I achieve that the query result will ignore inheritance and just return the described types?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that both the base and derived classes are registered as [query types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/query-types), thus EF Core considers them implementing the TPH database inheritance strategy (similar to normal entity types).

If you want to just share common properties, use a base class which is not registered as entity or query type.

In your case, change the name of the `CoasterExtended` class to let say `CoasterExtendedBase` and let both `CoasterExtended` and `CollectionItemExtended` inherit from it:

```
public class CoasterExtended : CoasterExtendedBase { }

public class CollectionItemExtended : CoasterExtendedBase
{
    // some additional properties
}
```

Now you can register both `CoasterExtended` and `CollectionItemExtended` as query types and everything will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

`Query` is actually superfluous here. This boils down to the logic of `FromSQL`. In other words, `Query<Foo>.FromSQL` is really just `FromSQL<Foo>`. In short, `FromSQL` can only work with entity types, i.e. types that are actually mapped to your database. This is why it's assuming relational inheritance with a `Discriminator` column. In other words, it's not meant for mapping to random C# object types.

**EDIT**

While the above is true, it's not comprehensive. It's better said that `DbSet<T>.FromSQL` must be an entity type. EF Core 2.1 added support for "query sets", but you must define such a query set on your context in order to utilize it:

```
public DbQuery<CollectionItemExtended> CollectionItemExtendeds { get; set; }
```

Then, you can utilize `FromSQL` on that:

```
_context.CollectionItemExtendeds.FromSQL(...);
```

Comment: Okey, thank for the answer. Is there any option to use sql procedures with EF core without so much pain? :) Without using ado.net and mapping everything manually?